# Springboot endpoint to return File

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm writting a custom Springboot Actuator Endpoint, and I would like to return a File. However, I can't find a way to return anything else than a JSON String.

My Endpoint is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyEndPoint implements Endpoint<URI> {

   @Override
   public String getId() {
       return "custoendpoint";
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isEnabled() {
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isSensitive() {
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public URI invoke() {
       File f = new File("C:/temp/cars.csv");
       return f.toURI();    
   }
}
```

When I access localhost:8080/custoendpoint, I'm receiving the path of my file ...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than implementing `Endpoint` you should implement `MvcEndpoint`. You then have access to the `HttpServletResponse` to which you can copy the contents of the file. For example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MvcEndpoint;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

class CustomEndpoint implements MvcEndpoint {

    @Override
    public String getPath() {
        return "/custom";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSensitive() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Endpoint<?>> getEndpointType() {
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void invoke(HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        FileCopyUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("c:/temp/cars.csv")),
                response.getOutputStream());
    }

}
```